# How to chain scope queries with OR instead of AND? Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to put 2 queries together in a scope - i am unsure where i am going wrong. your advise would be much appreciated

- I want to displays only users whose status is stated as "Accepted" or "nil"
- i wrote the below scope and tried others but no success

> ```
> scope :active_recruiters, -> {where(['status = ? OR status = ?', 'Accepted', 'IS NULL'])}
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `scope :active_recruiters, -> { where(status: ['Accepted', nil]) }`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to chain with OR instead of AND user AREL table constraint

```
scope = where( where(status: 'Accepted').arel.constraints.reduce( :and ).or( where(status: nil).arel.constraints.reduce( :and ) ) )
```

Comment: love arel, live arel. big thanks, i didn't know you can access arel in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

the query that you're trying to curate would look like this:

```
WHERE status = 'Accepted' OR status = 'IS NULL';
```

You're probably looking for something like this instead:

```
WHERE status = 'Accepted' OR status is null;
```

try this in your code

```
scope :active_recruiters, -> {where(['status = ? OR status ?', 'Accepted', 'IS NULL'])}
```

Even better though, how about this?

```
scope :active_recruiters, -> { where :status, [nil, 'Accepted'] }
```